# How to test a class that has only a small API but many private functions?

Tags: java, tdd

I am developing an interpreter for a graphical language that I am designing, and I want to apply TDD to my development process (all code in java). My interpreter has only one public function: `execute()` that executes the a given diagram. To execute the diagram, the class should use a number of internal (private) methods. I want to create these methods using TDD but since they are private I can't think of a way to access them. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make the methods package-private? Do they have to be tested individually given they are private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are the private functions complex enough that they need their own tests (i.e. multiple tests for execute won't cover them) ? If yes, maybe you need to break them out into collaborators especially if there are too many private methods. Writing tests against private methods will also hurt future refactoring i.e. let's say you merge/split some private functions, you'd have a bunch of tests to update even if the functionality for Execute() is still intact.
2. If not, just write as many tests for Execute() as needed to achieve desired confidence/path coverage

Comment: That is what I did. I created helper classes that provided the functions that were private as public methods and did the testing there

Answer (score 2):

You can always make the private methods package private and test them from a Test in the same package. This of course means that you need some discipline and do not attempt to call the same package private methods.

Comment: Everyone says that you should only test your public interfaces with TDD, so I thought there was a design problem in my thinking. So it is OK to test non-public methods in TDD?

Comment: yes of course it's ok. On integration test you should only use publuc interfaces methods but for unit test it's fine.

Comment: If your non public methods need to be tested then theres no harm in testing them. YOu can never have too many tests, sure its more work, but thats how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Put your test code in the same package, and change the private methods to have default (package) visibility instead. If you're worried about opening up the class too much, so that misbehaving code in the same package could do evil things, then move the class + test code to its own package.

Answer (score 1):

The way we do this sort of thing is to have files of tests (input and expected output). Throw data at the public function, and then check the result against the expected. 
Don't know how easy this would be for your case, but it keeps your test and production code implementation agnostic.